# Optional Where in Linq-to-SQL query

Tags: if-statement, linq-to-sql, where-clause

I'm trying to filter table only if `DateTime? start` is not null, but I get the exception that I touch `.Value` of null object. What is correct way to achieve this?

```
.Where(e => start.HasValue ? e.Timestamp >= start.Value : true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, guys, I found answer myself. This one works okay:

```
.Where(e => !start.HasValue || e.Timestamp >= start)
```

I looked in SQL Profiler -- Linq-to-SQL completely removes `Where` when `start` is null.